# Python Control Flow: if x is on the interval 0.0001 to 0.0624?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, control-flow

So what I'm trying to do is write a program that converts grams of flour to cups of flour and vice versa.

Because of cup measurements only come in 1/8 cup intervals (i.e., 0.125, 0.250 ...), I want the program to tell the user what measurement would be most appropriate, based on the decimal for people who aren't good with fractions or decimals. So if the answer returns a value with a decimal from `0001` to `0624` cups, the program will instruct the user that this is roughly equal to an exact amount of cups.

Or if the program returns a value with a decimal from 0.0625 to 0.1875 cups, the program will instruct the user that this is roughly equal to **`x`** and 1/8 cups.

So for example, 126 grams of flour is 1.008 cups, then the program will instruct the user that this is roughly equal to 1 cups. And if the result is 1.150, the user will be instructed that 1 and 1/8 cups is the most appropriate measurement.

This is what I have written, using `numpy` I can get a range of numbers from 0.0001 to 0.0624; however, I don't know how to use that in an `if` statement.

Basically what I want the program to do is take the decimal from the amount, and if that decimal falls on an interval (i.e., 0.0001 to 0.0624), then it will print, the best measurement for that interval.

This is confusing me quite a bit and I'm not entirely sure if I'm making this too hard, or what. Here's my code, it all works except for the part indicated.

```
print "Flour Conversion Program"

import numpy as np

flour_type   = raw_input( "What type of measurement do you want to use? " )
flour_recipe = raw_input( "What type of measurement does the recipe use? " )

if flour_type.lstrip() in ["Cups", "C", "cups", "cup", "c"] and flour_recipe.lstrip() in ["Grams", "Gram", "G", "g", "grams", "gram"]:

    grams_to_cups = float(0.008)
    flour_amount1 = raw_input("How many grams of flour does the recipe require? ")
    x = float(flour_amount1)
    print flour_amount1 + " grams of flour is " + str(x * grams_to_cups) + " cups."
    print str((x * grams_to_cups) % 1)

    #THIS IS THE PIECE OF CODE, I DON'T KNOW.
    if str((x * grams_to_cups) % 1).lstring() in str(np.arrange(0.0001, 0.0624, 0.0001)): 
    #THIS IS THE PIECE OF CODE, I DON'T KNOW.

        print str(x * grams_to_cups) + " is roughly " + str((x * grams_to_cups)-((x * grams_to_cups) % 1)) + " cups"

    else: 
        pass

else:
print "Invalid input"
```

If I tell my code to `print ( ( x * grams_to_cups ) % 1 )` it prints just the decimals like I want it to, and if I use `np.arrange( 0.0001, 0.0624, 0.0001 )` it lists all the correct values, but I don't know how to set it so that if my `( ( x * grams_to_cups ) % 1 )` is one of these values `np.arrange( 0.0001, 0.0624, 0.0001 )` to print something to the user.

I know this question is long, but I learnt python yesterday so I'm still really new, figuring things out, and any tips would also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Devil is hidden inside the matching "in"-constructor:

```
if () in ():  # fails, may be to your surprise, to match
```

---

Computers represent float numbers in several different ways, some of which are not "exact", some others are.

```
>>> grams_to_cups = float( 0.008 )
>>> 200 * grams_to_cups
1.6
>>> ( 200 * grams_to_cups ) % 1
0.6000000000000001
>>>
>>> np.arange( 0.0001, 0.628, 0.0001 )
array([ 0.0001,  0.0002,  0.0003,  0.0004,  0.0005,  0.0006,  0.0007,
        0.0008,  0.0009,  0.001 ,  0.0011,  0.0012,  0.0013,  0.0014,
        0.0015,  0.0016,  0.0017,  0.0018,  0.0019,  0.002 ,  0.0021,
        0.0022,  0.0023,  0.0024,  0.0025,  0.0026,  0.0027,  0.0028,
        ...
        0.6
        ...  ])
```

Looking just at the result of your **`%`** math part of the process ( without converting numbers to strings with `str()` ), the very last **`1`** after many, many, many `0`-s simply **prevents from matching any value produced by `np.arange()`**

Python Help ( reference ) may help you on exploring how to use accurate number representations, where needed, with an inbuilt **`Decimal`** numbers.

One of many pleasant python features is it´s ability to inspect objects:

```
   >>> str(( 200 * grams_to_cups ) % 1).__doc__
   str(object='') -> string
   Return a nice string representation of the object.
   If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.

   >>> dir( str(( 200 * grams_to_cups ) % 1) ) ['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__get slice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser',
   'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join',
   'ljust',
   'lower',
   'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', ' strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

---

This will help you polish one minor issue with an **`.lstring()`** method called in your code for an object, that does not understand it, as it has no such method implemented:

```
>>> str(( 200 * grams_to_cups ) % 1).lstring()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lstring'
```

This way you can verify your constructs one step after another and take corrective measures where needed.

**Wish you enjoy python more and more, Benscott, it can and will bring you a lot of powers for your further projects.**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the way to write the condition is:

```
if 0.001 < x * grams_to_cups < 0.0624:
```